# Navigates to URL but gets no response

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm using casperjs and I had an array of links and I was opening each page. the cycle of the array stopped at http://finishline.com/ all the time. It seems like I get no response. I isolated the situation I just cant get info from that link at all.

it just stops:

> ...
>   [info] [phantom] Running suite: 2 steps
>   [debug] [phantom] opening url: http://finishline.com/, HTTP GET
>   [debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://finishline.com/, type=Other,
>   willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
>   [debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://www.finishline.com/, type=Oth
>   er, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true

Here is the Isolation code:

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
    verbose : true,
    logLevel : "debug",
    pageSettings: {
        userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36",
         customHeaders: {
            "Server": "Apache/2.4.1 (Unix)"
        }
     },
    clientScripts: ["jquery.js"] ,
    viewportSize: {
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080
    }
});

casper.start().thenOpen("http://finishline.com")
.then(function(){
    console.log("title : ", this.getTitle())
})
casper.run();
```

Why can't I scrape or **get a response** from finishline?

how to handle if I cant get a response to continue with the code when there is no response?

Comment: Out of curiousity, why on request do you send these custom headers that are actually supposed to be response headers?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code using Slimerjs :

```
casperjs --engine=slimerjs my_casper_script.js
```

And it ran without issue:

```
    [info] [phantom] Starting... 
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 2 steps 
[debug] [phantom] opening url: http://finishline.com/, HTTP GET 
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://finishline.com/, type=Undefined, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true 
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "http://www.finishline.com/" 
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://a7474150781.cdn.optimizely.com/client_storage/a7474150781.html, type=Undefined, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false 
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://a7474150781.cdn.optimizely.com/client_storage/a7474150781.html, type=Undefined, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false 
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://cdns.us1.gigya.com/gs/webSdk/Api.aspx?apiKey=3_wvYmaqsebd4zKyXKtXex5iT6qVdAQNm8T5Vjh1LhGavP4EApJp4T5CcdKuXozmAe#origin=http://www.finishline.com/&hasGmid=false, type=Undefined, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false 
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://cdns.us1.gigya.com/gs/webSdk/Api.aspx?apiKey=3_wvYmaqsebd4zKyXKtXex5iT6qVdAQNm8T5Vjh1LhGavP4EApJp4T5CcdKuXozmAe#origin=http://www.finishline.com/&hasGmid=false, type=Undefined, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false 
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://4978775.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=4978775;type=aa;cat=links00;dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;tag_for_child_directed_treatment=;&ord=0.17442537640363165, type=Undefined, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false 
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://4978775.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=4978775;type=aa;cat=links00;dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;tag_for_child_directed_treatment=;&ord=0.17442537640363165, type=Undefined, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false 
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://login.dotomi.com/ucm/UCMController?dtm_com=28&dtm_fid=101&dtm_cid=61247&dtm_cmagic=963c2b&dtm_format=5&cli_promo_id=1&dtm_user_id=o867995714&dtmc_ref=&dtmc_loc=http%3A//www.finishline.com/&dtm_user_token=, type=Undefined, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false 
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://login.dotomi.com/ucm/UCMController?dtm_com=28&dtm_fid=101&dtm_cid=61247&dtm_cmagic=963c2b&dtm_format=5&cli_promo_id=1&dtm_user_id=o867995714&dtmc_ref=&dtmc_loc=http%3A//www.finishline.com/&dtm_user_token=, type=Undefined, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false 
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://20725988p.rfihub.com/ca.html?rfiidc=1048283195230333342&rfiaid=8c49df89b5394c92b2630ec07269f9c3&ver=9&rb=24949&ca=20725988&_o=24949&_t=20725988&pe=https%3A%2F%2F4978775.fls.doubleclick.net%2Factivityi%3Bdc_pre%3DCPyZuc2nuNQCFXah7Qod9IsPqg%3Bsrc%3D4978775%3Btype%3Daa%3Bcat%3Dlinks00%3Bdc_lat%3D%3Bdc_rdid%3D%3Btag_for_child_directed_treatment%3D%3B%26ord%3D0.17442537640363165&pf=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.finishline.com%2F&ra=82836050341159, type=Undefined, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false 
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://20725988p.rfihub.com/ca.html?rfiidc=1048283195230333342&rfiaid=8c49df89b5394c92b2630ec07269f9c3&ver=9&rb=24949&ca=20725988&_o=24949&_t=20725988&pe=https%3A%2F%2F4978775.fls.doubleclick.net%2Factivityi%3Bdc_pre%3DCPyZuc2nuNQCFXah7Qod9IsPqg%3Bsrc%3D4978775%3Btype%3Daa%3Bcat%3Dlinks00%3Bdc_lat%3D%3Bdc_rdid%3D%3Btag_for_child_directed_treatment%3D%3B%26ord%3D0.17442537640363165&pf=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.finishline.com%2F&ra=82836050341159, type=Undefined, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false 
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://dis.us.criteo.com/dis/dis.aspx?p=3616&cb=23181624377&ref=&sc_r=1280x1024&sc_d=24, type=Undefined, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false 
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://dis.us.criteo.com/dis/dis.aspx?p=3616&cb=23181624377&ref=&sc_r=1280x1024&sc_d=24, type=Undefined, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false 
[debug] [phantom] Automatically injected jquery.js client side 
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities 
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/2 http://www.finishline.com/ (HTTP 301) 
title :  Finish Line: Shoes, Sneakers & Athletic Gear 
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/2: done in 7686ms. 
[info] [phantom] Done 2 steps in 7694ms
```

when I ran your code using phantomjs as the engine I got the same result as you.
The instructions on how to install slimerjs are [here](https://slimerjs.org/).
But if you have npm installed you can install it with this command.

```
npm install slimerjs -g
```

hope this is of some assistance.

Comment: I'll test this out when I get a chance. Thanks for your input.

Comment: oh and if you are using Ubuntu I wrote a bash script that automates the whole installation of casperjs, slimerjs, phantomjs and the necessary graphical engines to make slimerjs fully headless you can get it [here](https://github.com/barthskywalker/Casperjs-install-for-Ubuntu)